# LibreOffice hide #VALUE

Tags: libreoffice

Can someone tell me how to hide in the cell the #VALUE! with conditional formatting or somehow?

A1 - DATE | B1 number (for ex.60) | C1 - DATE

When A1 cell which is DATE contains data (for example 2019.03.20) and the
B1 is for example 60 than C1=2019.05.19

I think it is okay to add sixty days to cell A1
But by default the A1 is empty and in this case, the C1 shows this error: #VALUE!

My question is, how to hide the #VALUE! text?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In any situation where you need to catch problems and show something else instead, use [IFERROR](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#IFERROR).

For example, set C1 to
`=IFERROR(A1+B1,"Missing date or days")`
or to have it be blank,
`=IFERROR(A1+B1,"")`